# What are the compatible spring boot versions for spring boot admin 2.2.2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, upgrade, spring-boot-admin

I have a Spring boot admin server with spring-boot-admin version 2.2.2.

I am trying to register spring boot client over mentioned spring boot server with client project having below configurations:

- Spring boot version: 2.6.0
- Spring boot cloud version: 2021.0.0
- Spring boot actuator version: 2.6.0
- Spring boot admin starter client version: 2.2.2

I am getting the below error in the client startup:

```json
{
  "instant": {
    "epochSecond": 1639544707,
    "nanoOfSecond": 994993000
  },
  "thread": "registrationTask1",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "loggerName": "org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler",
  "message": "Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task",
  "thrown": {
    "commonElementCount": 0,
    "localizedMessage": "'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties$Servlet org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getServlet()'",
    "message": "'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties$Servlet org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getServlet()'",
    "name": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
    "extendedStackTrace": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties$Servlet org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getServlet()'\n\tat de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ServletApplicationFactory.getManagementContextPath(ServletApplicationFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-admin-client-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]\n\tat de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ServletApplicationFactory.getManagementBaseUrl(ServletApplicationFactory.java:77) ~[spring-boot-admin-client-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]\n\tat de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.DefaultApplicationFactory.getHealthUrl(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:154) ~[spring-boot-admin-client-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]\n\tat de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.DefaultApplicationFactory.createApplication(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:80) ~[spring-boot-admin-client-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]\n\tat de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator.register(ApplicationRegistrator.java:58) ~[spring-boot-admin-client-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]\n\tat org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) [?:?]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]\n"
  },
  "endOfBatch": false,
  "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog",
  "threadId": 147,
  "threadPriority": 5,
  "timestamp": "2021-12-15T10:35:07.994+0530",
  "serviceName": "spring-boot-project",
  "serviceId": "spring-boot-project"
}
```

I have tried to register another spring boot client project over the same server with the below configurations and it is working fine as expected:

- Spring boot version: 2.5.2
- Spring boot cloud version: 2020.0.3
- Spring boot actuator version: 2.5.2
- Spring boot admin starter client version: 2.2.2

Are there any compatibility issues between Spring boot version 2.6.0 and spring boot admin version 2.2.2? Please let me know if there are any workarounds for this situation?

Comment: `I am not able to register` you got any errors/exceptions in log file?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I have updated issue with detailed logs, please look into them.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` yeah, looks like version incompatibility. Did you try to upgrade Spring boot admin starter client  as well? There are much newer versions  on Maven Central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-starter-client)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, actually I don't have privilege to upgrade spring boot admin client version on Server-side , it stays as it is 2.2.2. But I did try to upgrade spring boot admin client starter version in client project to latest one 2.5.4 and I received another error, as I/0 error on POST request for admin/instances

Comment: `I received another error, as I/0 error on POST request` please don't make  me guess it :)

Comment: Look at this table: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin - looks like you need spring-boot-admin 2.6+ for spring boot 2.6